# How to add link to orders page with filter inside link?

Tags: opencart

I want to add direct link with filter_date_added=(DATE(NOW()) in Dashboard in Opencart's Administration to orders page.

I'm not a programmer and if somebody can help me with this I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you a not a programmer may I suggest you searching the modules on OpenCart modules forum. Alternatively you can edit the `order_sales.tpl` in `view/templates` and simply add a column inside that and pull the variable from the PHP module.

The archiecture is found in

```
admin\controller\sale\order.php
admin\model\sale\order.php
admin\view\template\sale\order_list.tpl
admin\language\english\sale\order.php
```

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=14230

There is a module out there that allow you to do this for country, viewing sales by country. Maybe you can download and play around with it and try to experiment. It will only help you to become a better programmer.